# AWS Lambdaでエラー監視の結果をSlackに通知したい

Tags: aws, aws-lambda, aws-cloudwatch

最近社内で Lambda が増えてきて時々エラーやタイムアウトしてても気付かないことがあり
エラー監視して Slack に通知するようなことを行いたいです

すでに 20 以上のLambdaが動いていていろんな人が作っているため
１つ１つの Lambda に設定するのは大変なので

[Lambdaファンクションのエラーを通知したい（ファンクション名も込みで） - Qiita](https://qiita.com/onooooo/items/d14880780edcd34974a7)

こちらの記事を参考にして最後のSNS送信部分だけ 
Slack へのPOSTに変更すればできるのではと思っているのですが

> 「CloudWatchのメトリクス（Lambda＞全ての関数＞エラー(Errors)）」のメトリクスにセットしたアラームによって何らかのファンクションのエラー発生を検知し、これをトリガーにしてこのファンクションを起動させる。

というのがよくわかりません

Lambda のエラー数というアラームは作ってみたんですが
通知にはメールの設定しかなく
アクションにはオートスケーリングの設定しかないです

これをどうすれば Lambda のトリガーにできるんでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNS で Lambda を実行するということではないでしょうか？
SNS の送り先はメールだけじゃないです。

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html

Comment: できました！　メールアドレス入力欄しかなかったのでそういうものかと思ってました